# How to call a javascript function inside a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I did just a upgrade from RAILS 5 to RAILS 6 and I see that all rails views are not able to call a javascript function as before in RAILS 5.

I have an external javascript file located under

```
app/javascript/packs/station.js
```

This is is embeded in in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb as

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'station' %>
```

This is the code how I call the javascrpt function from html.erb file :

```
<%= text_field_tag(:station_text_field, ... ,
                    onkeyup: "javascript: request_stations(); ") %>
```

When I try to call a function thats is part of the station.js then I get an error in the browser developmer view: **ReferenceError: request_stations is not defined**

But I can also see in the brwoser view, under Debugger :

```
 Webpack / app/javascript / packs / station.js 
 and the javascript function I want to call.
```

So it seems that this script was loaded by the browser.

In contrast, when I just copy and paste these few lines that represent this javascript function direct into the template view file (...html.erb), something like :

```
<script>

function request_stations ()
{
    alert("calling request_stations");

};

</script>
```

then - it works as expected !

Comment: What if, instead of `application.html.erb`, you put `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'station' %>` in the specific view file that you need it in? (*c.f.*, [Adding a script that will be used by a specific file](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-javascript-to-your-rails-6-app/))

Comment: its the same behavior

Comment: In your browser, inspect the source using the dev tools and see if the javascript file is being included. I suspect that, for some reason, it's not.

Comment: What I already said, the browser was successfully loaded the javascript file.

Comment: You said that under the debugger, "... and the javascript function I want to call". What do you mean, exactly, by that? Are you able to call the function from the js console in the browser?

Comment: Check your `view source` it'll show the javascript being used.  Is it being added in?

Answer (score 1):

By default, variables/functions defined inside JavaScript files that are packed by Webpacker will not be available globally.

This is a good thing, because it prevents global naming conflicts. Generally speaking, you don't want to reference javascript functions/variables from your view. You instead want to write JavaScript in a way that attaches functionality to DOM nodes using their `id` or other attributes.

Here is a basic example based on the code you provided:

```
# in your rails view
<%= text_field_tag(:station_text_field, ..., id: 'station-text-field') %>
```

```
// in your javascript

function request_stations() {
    alert("calling request_stations");
};

const stationTextField = document.querySelector("#station-text-field");

stationTextField.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    request_stations();
});
```

Comment: I did an update of the question to show the HTML code how to call the function. This way works perfekcly in RAILS 5.

Comment: I don't know specifically why it worked for you in Rails 5, but I still would highly recommend not putting the event listener directly in your view unless you have to. I updated my example code to be relevant to the view code you added

Answer (score 0):

Agree with mhunter's answer.
This post helped me get a grounding on this difference in Rails 6: https://blog.capsens.eu/how-to-write-javascript-in-rails-6-webpacker-yarn-and-sprockets-cdf990387463

What I don't see in your question is whether or not you did this in app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("station")
```

The big difference in Rails 6 is that you have to deliberately:

- 1. require a JS file
- 2. deliberately export something from that file
- 3. deliberately import that something, in the file where you want to use it.

So if there is a function in `station.js` that you want to use, connect the steps above. Start with a simple function in `station.js` that fires upon DOMContentLoaded, and add a console.log("hey, station.js is alive and well"). If you don't see it, then something in those 3 steps is not right.

In pre-Rails6, you had a "garden" of JavaScript, just by virtue of being in the asset pipeline. In Rails 6, you have to be more deliberate.